# QML (Cascades) - insert container at position

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Cascades, 10.2 SDK

MyCustomContainer.qml:

```
import bb.cascades 1.2

Container {
    id: rootContainer

    Container{
        id: childContainer
        // some content
    }   
}
```

MyPage.qml:

```
import bb.cascades 1.2

Page {

    MyCustomContainer{

         Label{
              id: label
         }
    }
}
```

Label will be added on top of all content inside the rootContainer. I'd like to insert the label(or any other content) below all the content in MyCustomContainer. I've tried creating a property inside MyCustomContainer:

```
property Container backgroundContent
```

and add it as first child inside the MyCustomContainer as:

```
id: rootContainer

backgroundContent{
    id: backgroundContent
}
```

and just set it in MyPage as:

```
MyCustomContainer{
     backgroundContent: Container{

     }
```

but I get

> Cannot assign to non-existent property "id"

since the property value has not been set.

Can I somehow insert the content from MyPage.qml at the root of the MyCustomContainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather simple. Predict at which place can components be injected in the root container and place another container there.

```
Container {
id: rootContainer

Container{
    id: injectContainer
}

Container{
    id: childContainer
    // some content
}   
}

injectContainer.add(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a default property to assign any children of the MyCustomContainer to be placed into the childContainer.

```
import bb.cascades 1.2

Container {
    id: rootContainer

    default property content: childContainer.children

    Container{
        id: childContainer
        // All children when this control is used will be placed inside this component.
    }   
}
```

Then it can be naturally used as:

```
MyCustomContainer {
     Container {

     }
```

This will render the Container within the childContainer of the MyCustomContainer component.

Comment: I'm getting `mismatched input '.' expecting COLON`. `default property alias content` fixes the issue, but then I get `Invalid alias location`. It looks like there is no children property on Container?

Comment: There should be children on every component. Its a property on QObject. Are you sure you put a colon after the alias name?

Comment: There is no children property in Cascades AFAIK.

Comment: Random blast from the past here. Unless cascades provides its own custom QObject implementation it should be there.  I suppose it could be that bb cascades uses a version of QT before I started working with it that did not have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using backgroundContent.add()